# How do I add custom color to Tiny editors?

Tags: tinymce

I have installed TinyMCE 5 editor on my website. I need to add 4 personal color to editor, How do I add custom color to Tiny editor? or How do I edit available color in Tiny editor?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKJDt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the TinyMCE documentation around what you can do with the color options:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#textcoloroptions

To address the colors in the picker this specific option exists:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#color_map